# Why is systemd sending so many pings to watchdog?

Tags: embedded-linux, systemd, watchdog

I have configured systemd with `RuntimeWatchdogSec=10`

Systemd is sending A LOT of pings to the watchdog device in beginning (1500 in first 5 seconds). Every once a while, it acts normally i.e. one or two pings with 5 sec interval and goes nuts again. Any idea what's causing this?

I am using systemd v204 on an embedded linux distribution, developed in-house

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming-specific questions; general software support questions are off-topic. Your question may be more appropriate on Super User.

Comment: Also asked at http://superuser.com/questions/992951/ .

Comment: I've asked at both sites after the above comment

Answer (score 1):

- Systemd does its house keeping work and ping in the same loop.
- So when systemd is free from its house keeping work it will wait for half the specified value of RuntimeWatchdogSec and it will do ping.
- In startup systemd is loaded with its work queue, so it will ping very often.

The code looks something similar to this,

```
while (cond)
{
    if (cond1)
        watchdog_ping(); /* Ping happens here */

    if (task1_queue() > 0)
        continue;

    if (task2_queue() > 0)
        continue;

    if (task3_queue() > 0)
        continue;

    /* ...... */

     /* Sleep for half the RuntimeWatchdogSec time */
     do_wait();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The immense number of pings take place not only in the init phase, it does that _every time_ it wakes up, which in my opinion is not optimal